# Every keystroke in tinyMCE seems to connect to the server

Tags: angularjs, tinymce

I have an AngularJS web application which uses the AngularUI wrapper for TinyMCE from https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce.

The problem I am facing is that when editing content in the tinyMCE editor, there seems to be a server call on every keystroke. Everything works fine but a server call on every keystroke, makes for a bad editing experience on a slow network and also results in unnecessary network traffic.

The relevant parts of my code are below:

Included .js files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-tinymce/dist/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

The textarea directive:

```
<textarea ui-tinymce="ctrl.tinymceOptions" ng-model="ctrl.content.body"></textarea>
```

tinyMCE Options in the controller:

```
ctrl.tinymceOptions = {
        plugins: 'link image code media wordcount spellchecker fullscreen charmap hr table lists',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | table charmap link image   media | code fullscreen',
        menubar: false,
        br_in_pre: false
 }
```

Can anyone help me understand why this might be happening and if there is a solution for this?

Comment: What server call are you seeing?  TinyMCE does not call out to a server on its own if you are using the standard plugins that come with the open source product.

Comment: The server calls are to my own domain. In the console I can see the page resources being requested again but the page doesn't refresh or anything. I don't think it's a TinyMCE issue but possibly something to do with AngularJS TinyMCE wrapper or some other aspect of using TinyMCE with AngularJS.